# update preferences in android

Tags: android, android-layout

**i have created Shared preferences in LoginActivity class**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = null;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;
preferences=getSharedPreferences("LoginActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(preferences!=null)
        {
        edit_pass.setText(preferences.getString("PASSWORD", ""));
        edit_user.setText(preferences.getString("USERNAME", ""));
        }
```

this is working fine.
but **Now i want to update preferences in MyProfile Activity class, PLZ help me** 
and sorry for bad English 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store values in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences("LoginActivity").edit();
editor.putString("PASSWORD", edit_pass.getText().toString());  
editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this-

```
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("USERNAME", "new_value_for_user");
edit.commit();
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: as its working you must accept it as answers rather than changing it

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way,

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("LoginActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("PASSWORD", value);
editor.putString("USERNAME", value);
editor.commit();
```

Hope this helps you.